# pixel level regression with large raster dataset

Tags: r, r-raster

I am trying to fit a `glm` model where `y, x1 + x2....xn` are layers in a `rasterStack` object. I have tried converting the raster stack to a `dataframe`object but I get a vector size error as shown below. instead, I'd like to try fitting the regression model with raster layers as the input - without having to convert the layers to a data frame given the file size and memory error. Would that be possible and how would you configure that?
The model that I'd line to fit is of nature: `m1<-glm(y1~x1 + x2, family=binomial(), data=layers)`, but I don't get to this point because I cant convert the data to a dataframe for model fitting.

```
dat<-as.data.frame(stack(layers[c(y1,x1,x2)]))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 40GB
```

Comment: The data seems to be too large. Did you try to test with a small part of the data? What data type (e.g. csv, ...) do you have?

Comment: Small parts of the data would work. The data type is `rasterStack` with 5 layers and I get the error when trying to convert the `rasterStacks` to data frame. But maybe I don't have to convert and could fit the model directly to `rasterStacks`?

Comment: I have never used raster. What about dat1<-as.data.frame(stack(layers[c(y1)])) and so on. Perhaps you can merge the important part afterwards?

Comment: I see your point. However loading 1-n layers as data frame separately doesn't seem to solve the memory issue. My workaround is to feed the raster layers directly without having to convert..hence my question.

Comment: I would subset the data into smaller parts and then try to fit the regression model on every subset. Check if you get significantly different coefficients in each subset. If not, then just use the most plausuble model or average the coefficents and build a generalized model from there.

Comment: Makes sense, Martin. I have subset the raster using several different extents and run glm separately on those. I then run those models in model selection and averaging framework in `MuMIn` package.

Comment: Glad it help, and thanks for sharing information on `MuMIn`, I didn't know this package before.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some regression examples with Raster* data (from ?calc):

Create example data

```
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
s1 <- lapply(1:12, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3)))
s2 <- lapply(1:12, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3)))
s1 <- stack(s1)
s2 <- stack(s2)
```

Regression of values in one brick (or stack) with another

```
s <- stack(s1, s2)
# s1 and s2 have 12 layers; coefficients[2] is the slope
fun <- function(x) { lm(x[1:12] ~ x[13:24])$coefficients[2] }
x1 <- calc(s, fun)
```

Regression of values in one brick (or stack) with 'time'

```
time <- 1:nlayers(s)
fun <- function(x) { lm(x ~ time)$coefficients[2] }
x2 <- calc(s, fun)
```

Get multiple layers, e.g. the slope *and* intercept

```
fun <- function(x) { lm(x ~ time)$coefficients }
x3 <- calc(s, fun)
```

In some cases, a much (> 100 times) faster approach is to directly use linear algebra and pre-compute some constants

```
# add 1 for a model with an intercept
X <- cbind(1, time)

# pre-computing constant part of least squares
invXtX <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X)

## much reduced regression model; [2] is to get the slope
quickfun <- function(y) (invXtX %*% y)[2]
x4 <- calc(s, quickfun)
```

Comment: I previouly apologise if this is a noob question, but wouldn't it violate independence assumptions in regression if you use pixels as individual observations?

Comment: That would depend on what the grid cells (pixels) represent; and whether that assumption is actually relevant for your case. Also, do you consider independence between layers (for a cell) or between cells (for a layer), or both?