# Pixelwise regression on rasters in R

Tags: r, regression, gis, raster

I am performing a pixelwise regression on 4 different raster files, each representing a different time stamp of a coastal dune. My goal is to calculate the slope of elevation change, to see which areas show the fastest growth in elevation.

They have been resampled to have the same resolution, and were then stacked.
I then wanted to perform a regression analysis on them (which I found here: [pixel level regression with large raster dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452955/pixel-level-regression-with-large-raster-dataset)). I however got an error, and it think it is something silly (I am quite new to raster analyses) but I do not seem to figure it out.
This is my code:

```
dem18 = raster("20220912_0216419_DUDE Oostende_T18_DEM.tif")
dem1  = raster("20210223_DUDE_Oostende_T1_DEM.tif")
dem3  = raster("20210430_0216404_DUDE Oostende_T3_DEM.tif")
dem15  = raster("20220419_0216416_DUDE Oostende_T15_DEM.tif")


dem1 = resample(dem1, dem18) 
dem3 = resample(dem3, dem18)
dem15 = resample(dem15, dem18)
dem_stacked = stack(dem1, dem3, dem15, dem18)
plot(dem_stacked,  xlim = x_lim, ylim = y_lim, col = terrain.colors(100))
```

This is the plot:
[image]

This is my regression:

```
func =  function(val) { summary(lm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x = val, y = 1:4)))$coefficients[2,1]}

slope = calc(dem_stacked, func)
plot(slope)

Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
cannot use this function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is your indexing in the regression. Try something like this:

```r
library(raster)

#test dataset
set.seed(32)
dem1 <- raster(matrix(runif(9, 1, 10), 3, 3))
dem2 <- raster(matrix(runif(9, 1, 20), 3, 3))
dem3 <- raster(matrix(runif(9, 1, 100), 3, 3))
dem4 <- raster(matrix(runif(9, 1, 300), 3, 3))

dem_stacked <-  stack(dem1, dem2, dem3, dem4)
plot(dem_stacked)
```

[image]

```r
func <-  function(val) { 
  summary(lm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x = val, y = 1:4)))$coefficients[2,1] 
  }

slopes <- calc(dem_stacked, func)


plot(slopes)
```

[image]

```r
#test regression on one pixel stack
func(as.vector(dem_stacked[1,1]))
#> [1] 0.01707964
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your code but I still get the same error. I updated my question.